# Reasons NOT to open source not-for-profit code?

Tags: licensing, open-source, closed-source

I am a big fan of open source code. I think I understand most of the advantages of going open source. I'm a science student researcher, and I have to work with quite a surprising amount of software and code that is not open source (either it's proprietary, or it's not public). I can't really see a good reason for this, and I can see that the code, and people using it, would definitely benefit from being more public (if nothing else, in science it's vital that your results can be replicated if necessary, and that's much harder if others don't have access to your code).

Before I go out and start proselytising, I want to know: **are there any good arguments for *not* releasing not-for-profit code publicly, and with an OSI-compliant license?**

*(I realise there are a few [similar](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/61091/to-open-source-or-not-to-open-source-that-is-the-question) [questions](http://www.brightjourney.com/q/advantages-disadvantages-making-source-code-public) on around, but most focus on situations where the code is primarily used for making money, and I couldn't much relevant in the answers.)*

**Clarification:** By "not-for-profit", I am including downstream profit motives, such as parent-company brand-recognition and investor profit expectations. In other words, the question relates only to software for which there is NO profit motive tied to the software what so ever.

Comment: +1 as I find that an interesting question myself. But I do wonder if this is the right place to ask this. Maybe you'd get different perspectives from other SE sites, like the PM.SE site. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @haylem, I hadn't seen PM.SE, but that seems like it's more for technical aspects of project management?

Comment: Will you actively maintain the project afterwards or is it a code graveyard.  In other words, what is the future of the project.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: yes, I'm assuming active maintenance, development, and use of the code.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to take into account that open sourcing your code might require additional effort.

As an example, in this blog entry Sun/Oracle engineer describes efforts they had to take when open sourcing their code: [Open Source or Dirty Laundry?](https://blogs.oracle.com/smarks/entry/open_source_or_dirty_laundry)

> As we get ready to dive into the open source world, one of the many activities that's occurring is the preparation of the code for being open sourced. There are some obvious things that need to be done. For instance, our source code includes a mixture of code that we've written and code that we've licensed from others. We'll need to separate out the latter and open source only the appropriate pieces of code.
>
> Another preparation activity is "scrubbing" the code of proprietary information, mentions of particular customers, developers, technologies etc. This is a little less obvious, but consider the following example:
>
> ```
> /\*
>  \* HACK - insert a time delay here because the stupid Intertrode
>  \* Technologies framebuffer driver will hang the system if we
>  \* don't. Those guys over there must really be idiots.
>  \*/
> ```
>
> While all of the above might be true, we probably have a relationship of some sort with Intertrode Tech and having comments like this in the code could hurt our business somehow and so it should be removed. Arguably it shouldn't have been there in the first place, but now's the time to take it out.
>
> Another part of the "scrubbing" activity is to remove profanity and other "undesirable" words...

Note all above changes had to be made to code that has been considered perfectly OK as closed source - that makes it pure **extra effort** so to speak.

Comment: Well, this applies for big companies with existing code-base, much less for code that is written to be Open Source from scratch.

Comment: @KonradRudolph OP mentioned _I have to work with... code that is not open source (either it's proprietary, or it's not public)_ meaning it has not been there from scratch

Comment: Didn't the same thing happen with DOOM 3? [Patent Issue Delays Doom 3 Source Code Release](http://news.slashdot.org/story/11/11/16/1354222/patent-issue-delays-doom-3-source-code-release)

Answer (score 11):

**Security.**

For example, say you build a web framework and you yourself use it.

As a not-for-profit project, you haven't had the time to dedicate to inspecting every bit of code for vulnerability to one attack or another:

- CSRF
- XSS
- SQL injection
- Session fixation
- Use of buggy third-party libraries or even languages

Now, having open-sourced the project, you allow friendly eyes to contribute, but you also allow malicious eyes full insight into your work, and, if they find a server that is running your code, you've eliminated your ability to hide your imperfections in obscurity.

Of course, this may not apply to the type of software you are working on; and as always **obscurity is no excuse for laziness in security.**

However, just like I found in the couple of the levels that I got through in the [Stripe capture the flag game](https://stripe.com/blog/capture-the-flag-wrap-up), knowing the code is the among the easiest ways to find vulnerabilities (and sometimes it can be the only way).

Comment: This debate has been going on for ages, and my impression was that open source is better for security, but only if the project is fairly popular (among developers at least). It's odd that there's not a really good run-down of the arguments anywhere on the 'net (that I can find, anyway).

Comment: In Combination with naught101s comment that makes a lot of sense. If to less people care about your source and you're using in in production the chances are pretty good that someone "evil" will inspect it and use it against you (eventually)

Comment: Security through obscurity?

Comment: @lechlukasz Did you even read the whole post?

Comment: This may be a relevant read: [Open vs. Closed Source](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4441/open-source-vs-closed-source-systems) TLDR; Open source is not inherently safer (or less safe) than closed source

Comment: @Oleksi Thanks, but I know that. I said "obscurity is no excuse for laziness in security." This question is not about the open vs. closed, it's about *opening* a previously closed system.  I happen to completely agree with the link you posted, but developers are not perfect and when you open source a system there is a chance that the first eyes to find a bug will exploit it instead of fix it for you.

Comment: [Kerckhoff's Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle) says that any serious discussion of security must begin with the assumption that "the adversary knows the system" already, and therefore opening the source cannot possibly make it worse.  This may not necessarily be true, but it's a far better starting point than assuming that you're secure because the adversary is too dumb to find vulnerabilities without looking at the code.

Comment: @MasonWheeler The issue is for an organization with limited resources and unlimited ways to spend those resources, a "serious discussion of security" might not actually be warranted.  I think it's nice to put "security" above all else, but reality is that it needs to be balanced with every business need.  And of course, a good software engineer will be able to keep security high at any level of design, but that is where the discussion of limited resources comes into play.  I couldn't in good conscience recommend opensourcing based on "you should have security figured out anyway".

Answer (score 10):

A good reason not to open source is that some of your source might be copyrighted. How often don't you search the web for a quick solution to a problem and just take the snippet of code you find?

Well, those might be copyrighted and I don't know if the author would like finding his code being relicensed under a different license.

Comment: +1 for copyrighted. Just wanted to add patents as well. You might just find out that your open-source project is infringing on some of the thousands upon thousands of software patents inhabited by the "corps". Streaming video? Patented. Pay-per-click ads? Patented. Just some examples. However, chances are the "corps" don't care - unless you're a competitor.

Comment: Hehe. That's not really an argument against open source, but against piracy. But you're right, I bet this is a problem in a lot of large private code.

Comment: @naught101 Agreed. Open source only exposes the problem. Closed proprietary in this case is a matter of not getting caught ;)

Comment: So you are saying that one reason to keep source closed is to allow you to hide casual copyright violations? Don't you think that's a rather unethical reason to use?

Comment: Unethical....maybe, a very very good reason to not open source, certainly.

Answer (score 6):

You need to be careful with how you choose your license to avoid potential liability issues.

A  lawyer may be a better person to talk to about this, but the general idea is what happens if someone uses (or misuses) the application and it causes some harm? Are you responsible? Obviously this would depend on what *type* of software you are writing, but you always need to be careful with what your license says about your liability. This can be a tricky thing to get right, so it may be easier to just not release the source code.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point, and most OS licenses usually have some arse-covering text in there somewhere. I guess I was assuming a "no-liability accepted" type license.

Answer (score 4):

*Warning: [I Am Not A Lawyer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANAL).*

Well, if it's a not-for-profit and its intellectual property is strongly tied to the software's code, then some may want to protect it from being commercially re-used, or even abusively exploited to create carbon-copies of your software.

Some other reasons - which are probably deep-rooted in the first one, actually - are that in your case a lot of the high-end research happens with private funding, and usually the investors want to see ROI. And so far, no all actors of the software industry (or newcomers) have been fully persuaded of the viability of the open source model (most likely by lack of knowledge and understanding of licensing, or by simple fear that licensing won't prevent malicious uses and copies).

Additionally, these companies don't want to get sued back by the ones who attempted to make a profit on their backs, and licensing is seen as a safeguard in this regard as well, with good reason or not.

It may not appear so, but maybe not-for-profit organizations ARE profitable for their founders or investors. The benefits just aren't direct. So they have a great interest in the NFPs going strong and not being beaten to the curb by competitors (even though you also wouldn't often think of "competitors" in the not-for-profit market), and they want to preserver their IP, even if it's at the cost of not getting more free eye-balls to review their code to find problems and improve it early on.

Note as well that copyright laws differ from country to country. Many European countries consider US copyright laws and the US patent system to be rather dumbstruck, for instance, so there's a cultural background and weight that is hard to shake off.

Jut my 2 cents on the subject.

*(I've worked with universities a lot, and recently in bioinformatics and healthcare... It's a recurrent question for me and my colleagues :) )*

Comment: Hrm.. I was kind of considering the code and the IP together in my question. Maybe I should have made that clearer. I would think of ROI and branding considerations as profit motives... (I realise that "science" was a bit vague, and that lots of science is profitable - my field (earth system sciences definitely isn't though).

Comment: Clarified the question. Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: I'd consider your field to be profitable. It may not have a wide market, but it doesn't mean it's not profitable. In fqct, I'd consider it to be involving fairly big money. Why do you feel otherwise?

Comment: I'm in climate modelling. No-one pays for climate models. No-one pays to use climate models. There is no profit to be made from using the software. People get paid to do research using those models (and this often includes writing the models), and computing time is sometimes paid for, but both of these mean that sharing code would make things cheaper (more time to spend on research instead of writing code, less time wasted on HPC facilities). I don't really see how the software is related to any profitability.

Comment: @naught101: I don't know, it's not my area, but I have a friend, who did a thesis in oceanography relating to climate modelling, who was saying it's an active field. And considering climate modelling uses the biggest cluster computers ever built, I'd think people are interested in funding this kind of research, if only companies specializing in producing meteorological equipment, nagivational systems, or even involved in more funky stuff that will benefit from such models (terraformation comes to mind, or green energy production).

Comment: @naught101: But as I said... I'm clueless here, just wondering. Maybe there's no real application and buy-in yet. Just looks like there is potential ahead.

Comment: I wouldn't disagree that there are profits being made in the system as a whole, I just don't think that they are related particularly to the software.

Comment: @naught101 - If the model is accurate enough someone could short corn futures or something.  What about re-insurance companies that basically only pay out when there are large natural disasters?  If a model is actually more accurate than others I'm sure there are ways to make $ from it.

Comment: @psr: I think that's naught101's point: there are profitable outcomes to the results of the model's uses, but not necessarily much money being done in selling software implementing the model. Surprises me as well, but could very well be.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two different kinds of open source.

If your attitude is "here's something useful, I'm done with it" (and that turns out to be accurate) then there's little downside.

On the other hand, if your attitude is "I'm really excited and I want some real users to help drive future development" then think very carefully.   You will have to spend time supporting users, many of whom are clueless.  You will have to consider conflicting requests for features and enhancements.   You will find it increasingly difficult to make changes, to preserve backward compatibility.

Comment: I don't really see how releasing code obliges anyone to provide support? And in science at least, most of the users are pretty clued up, at least about the process, if not the code itself.

Comment: @naught101: Obligates no, but if anyone uses your code, you *will* get e-mails, questions, suggestions... which *will* take some effort to handle, unless you simply choose to ignore them. Outside science, many users aren't too clued up so you may find yourself helping folks with elementary set-up issues etc. simply because you  happened to release some code. I've experienced that, at least. Even BSD-style disclaimers "provided as is" etc. don't - and *shouldn't* - stop people from asking help.

Comment: Upvoted because this answer isn't really any less applicable than many others. @JoonasPulakka: of course it shouldn't stop people from asking for help. But it should stop them expecting an answer. Also, if you've got the actual software out in public, then presumably you have the same responsibility to users *regardless* of whether your *code* is public (depending on the EULA, perhaps). Maybe you have to expect more queries from *developers* if you release the code, but it'd be nice to think that most of them will have a bit of a clue, and might repay some advice a patch or two..